# Time Series Mean Square Convergence with given acvf

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, time-series, mean-square-error

Let $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a stationary time series with $E[X_t]=0$ and acvf

$\gamma(h)={1}_{0}(h)+\rho1_{h \ne0}(h)$
with $\rho \in (0,1)$.

Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_{-j}$ converges in $L^2$.

I tried to compute the $L^2$ limit straightforward, but got $0$ as a result, which cannot be true since the limit is supposed to be a RV with expectation $0$ and variance $\rho$.

Comment: Is $1_0(h)$ an indicator function? Does the notation mean that $1_A(h) = 1$ when $h\in A$ and that $1_0(h)$ is a short-hand for $1_{\{0\}}(h)$?

Comment: Yeah, i couldnt figuere it out how to write it like that. So basicly the RV's have variance $1$ and covariance $\rho$

Comment: Let $Y_t=\sqrt{1-\rho}\varepsilon'+\sqrt{\rho}\varepsilon_k$, then $\gamma_Y(h)=\gamma_X(h)$ and $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^nY_j\to \sqrt{1-\rho}\varepsilon'$.

Comment: Correct the above comment : Let $Y_t=\sqrt{\rho}\epsilon'+\sqrt{1-\rho}\epsilon_k$, where $\{epsilon_k \}$ is a white noise sequence and noncorrelated with $\epsilon'$, then $\gamma_Y(h)= \gamma_X(h)$ and $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^nY_j \to \sqrt\rho\epsilon'$.

Comment: Correct the above comment : Let $Y_k=\sqrt{\rho}\epsilon'+\sqrt{1-\rho}\epsilon_k$, where $\{\epsilon_k \}$ is a white noise sequence, $\mathsf{E}[\epsilon^2]=\mathsf{E}[(\epsilon')^2]=1$, $ \mathsf{E}[\epsilon']=0$ and $\mathsf{cov}(\epsilon_k,\epsilon')=0$, then $\gamma_Y(h)= \gamma_X(h)$ and $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^nY_j \to \sqrt\rho\epsilon'$.